# Sublime Text 2 - There are no packages available for installation

Tags: sublimetext2, package-control

So many Sublime Text 2 users get `error (or) no action` when they want to install any sublime text 2 package @via Package Control.

When I'm clicked on `Package Control: Install Package` from `Ctrl+Shift+P`.

I got this below error:

**There are no packages available for installation**

[image]

**Note:** Some times error message is not displayed and no action is happened.

When I'm tracing error report from console. I got this below error on console.

```
Package Control: Trying to execute command /usr/bin/curl --user-agent 'Sublime Package Control v2.0.0' --connect-timeout 30 -sSL --compressed --dump-header /tmp/tmpwQjJVT --header 'If-Modified-Since: Sun, 03 Aug 2014 12:10:13 GMT' --cacert /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -v https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json
Package Control: Curl HTTP Debug General
  Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    Trying 50.116.34.243...
    Trying 2600:3c02:e000:42::1...
  connect to 2600:3c02:e000:42::1 port 443 failed: Network is unreachable
  Failed to connect to sublime.wbond.net port 443: Network is unreachable
  Closing connection 0
Package Control: Error downloading channel. curl: (7) Failed to connect to sublime.wbond.net port 443: Network is unreachable downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
error: Package Control

There are no packages available for installation
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This error is happened with IPv6 problem. If your Internet Service
>   Provider (ISP) does not support for IPv6 you will get this error.

**How to solve this on Unix (OSX/Linux/Ubuntu/CentOS/etc...):**

Open terminal and run this below command line.

```
sudo echo "50.116.34.243 sublime.wbond.net" >> /etc/hosts
```

**How to solve this on Windows:**

> Click on **start** button on your windows desktop and find **cmd**.
>   
>   Now right click on **Command Prompt** option and select **Run as administrator**.

Run this below command line on CMD.

```
echo 50.116.34.243 sublime.wbond.net >> "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Comment: Asked question in 2 sec ago and gaven answer in 0 sec ago huh!!

Comment: @RakeshShetty , By Q&A share knowledge.

Comment: You can make your own blog for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Blog is not for only making money who said you that

Comment: @RakeshShetty , Yes I know. But I don't want to start blog for only one post (about this) :)

Comment: If people google properly then they can find this solution on sublimetext forum

Comment: Please do not do this. Since I wrote Package Control and run the server, I can tell you this is a brittle solution that will break. In fact, the URL and IP for the server are changing soon. Instead, use the latest version from https://github.com/wbond/package_control. If you still have trouble, post an issue with a debug log.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I am able to install packages, but not see this error when I tried to upgrade.

Comment: this didn't fix the problem.  Instead, I deleted my "Packages/Package Control" folder and cloned https://github.com/wbond/package_control into the original path.  Restarted ST2, got a message about auto update of a package & prompted me to re-start, which resolved my issues.  Package Control is now working again.

Answer (score 6):

Do not hard-code the current ip of sublime.wbond.net. This will not solve the problem, and will only break your machine's connection to Package Control in the near future.

If you are having trouble with ipv6, use the latest version from https://github.com/wbond/package_control. It has a fix for curl and wget when they encounter issues with computers that provide ipv6 via DNS, but can not actually access sites via ipv6.

If you are still having trouble with Package Control, follow the instructions at https://packagecontrol.io/docs/issues. Please be sure to include a debug log, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: Not only this is a good reply, but it apparently comes from the creator of the project himself. I believe this guy knows a little about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Three stps to solve this problem on Mac in China.

1. add "0.116.34.243 sublime.wbond.net" into /etc/host
2. open Global Mode of Shadowsocks (needed only in China)
3. restart Sublime

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and after a long search I found out that **packagecontrol.io** website was down!